# Python 3.0+ setting to max 4 decimal and rounding

Tags: python, string, numbers, decimal, rounding

So I have an assignment to match an expected output: 34.7381. But I am getting 34.73809999999999. I realize that it is just a rounded number with only 4 decimal places but I have no clue how to that in a short step.

I could brute force it and check for the placement of the decimal point, checking how many characters are after it, eliminating all of them and doing the rounding myself. But that seems rather complicated and stupid for something so simple.

Thanks you for your help!

Comment: Are you using `float` or `Decimal`?  You cannot get precise decimal results with a `float`, although you might be able to output a rounded result or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [round function](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html?highlight=round#round)?

```
a = 34.73809999999999
print round(a, 4)
>>> 34.7381
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use string formatting:

```
>>> '{:0.4f}'.format(34.7381)
    '34.7381'
>>> '{:0.4f}'.format(34.73809999999999)
    '34.7381'
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about it, and just specify the precision you want in your printing:

```
>>> print('{:.4f}'.format(34.73809999999999))
34.7381
```